# Printing output to file with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that takes a file as input, looks up all the email addresses, and writes them to a designated file.

based on other similar questions, i have ended up with this:

```
import re

    Input = open("inputdata.txt", "r")
    regex = re.compile("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")
    Logfile = "Result.txt"


        for line in Input:
            query = regex.findall(line)
            for line in query:
                print >>Logfile, query
```

what am i doing wrong? this outputs nothing.
i am guessing the main problem is "for line in query:", which i have tried changing without any luck.

Cheers!

Edit: i have changed the script as suggested below, with "print (query)" instead.
i still do not get any output.
current script is:

```
import re

Input = open("Inputdata.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")
# logfile = "Result.txt"

for line in Input:
    query = regex.findall(line)
    for line in query:
        with open("Result.txt", "a") as logfile:
            logfile.write(line)
```

It outputs nothing, and tells me: " NameError: name "logfile" not defined".
what causes this, and is this the reason there is no output?

Comment: Concerning your edit: I do not get a name error for that code; are you sure you are using this exact code? Note that I changed the variable from `Logfile` to `logfile` (i.e. lower case) to comply to coding conventions. Also, you do not have to open the file anew in each iteration. Move the `with ...` line on top of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Logfile` variable is just the *name* of a file, not an actual `file` object. Also, you should use `with` to automatically close the file when you are done. Try this:

```
with open("Result.txt", "a") as logfile:
    print >>logfile, "hello world"
    print >>logfile, "another line"
```

But note that in Python 3.x, the syntax is different, as `print` is no longer a statement but [a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
with open("Result.txt", "a") as logfile:
    print("hello world", file=logfile)
    print("another line", file=logfile)
```

Thus, instead of redirecting `print`, the best choice might be to `write` to the file directly:

```
with open("Result.txt", "a") as logfile:
    logfile.write("hello world\n")
    logfile.write("another line\n")
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this.
The working script looks like this, and now outputs correctly:
import re

Input = open("Input.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")
# logfile = open("Result.txt", "a")

with open("Result.txt", "a") as logfile:
    for line in Input:
        query = regex.findall(line)
        for query in Input:
            logfile.write(query)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, with `print` you can write to a file without redirecting the output to a file. The way you have used the `print`, I guess, you want output redirection only.

Let's say your python script is in a file `test.py`.
replace the line:

```
print >>Logfile, query
```

with just:

```
print query
```

And from a terminal/cmd, run the script like this:

```
python test.py >> Result.txt
```

This is called output redirection.